# Is there any way to get the range of colors used in ImageMagick's -fuzz option?

Tags: colors, imagemagick

I'm trying to hack together an image search that uses color "distance," (or "tolerance", or "variance") similar to what's done in ImageMagick's `-fuzz` option: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#fuzz_distance.

What I'm hoping to get is **a range or an array of some RGB values** from a single initial pixel that I can use to match against comparison points in a database.

Obviously what's happening with `-fuzz` is some Euclidean distance formula describing a sphere in the RGB cube, but I'm not sure where to find the mathematics or how to use ImageMagick (or some other library) to accomplish this.

Thoughts?

Comment: Carsten's answer is perfect within this question, nothing to add. Official sources match is info. http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#fuzz_distance

Answer (score 3):

As stated [here in MageMagick's forums](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?p=66336#p66336), color `B` is within the fuzz range `R` of color `A` if their euclidian distance is lower than R:

```
sqrt((B.r - A.r)^2 + (B.g - A.g)^2 + (B.b - A.b)^2) < R
```

`r`, `g` and `b` stand for the colors' respective red, blue and green values.

If you don't have transparency, that's it. If you do need to consider transparency, you have to multiply the colors by their respective alpha channel value before using them in the formula.

In the 3-dimensional RGB color space, the colors within a fuzz range of a certain color do indeed form a sphere (of radius `R`).

For checking agains points in your database, you can just check with the formula if they are inside the sphere.

Regarding color ranges: Since the range of "fuzzy" (= within fuzz range :-) ) colors for one dimension depends on the position in the other two dimensions, the only thing you could generate is the enclosing cube around your fuzzy sphere. That won't give you the right colors, but you could use it to reject all colors that lie outside of the cube.
The ranges for this cube are:

```
(A.r - R) <= B.r <= (A.r + R)
(A.g - R) <= B.g <= (A.g + R)
(A.b - R) <= B.b <= (A.b + R)
```

**Update:**

[Here is the code reference](http://trac.imagemagick.org/browser/ImageMagick/trunk/magick/color.c?rev=3272#L1743) for the calculation. It looks a bit more complicated, but that is because it also has to handle CMYK colors. For RGB, it reduces to the above-mentioned case.